# Deleting border on <img> with CSS background-image and moving it little bit down

Tags: html, css, background-image

this is my `HTML`

```
<p>
    <b>Contact for place A</b><br>
    <img class="mail"> your@email.com<br>
    <img class="phone"> +000 111 222 333
</p>
<p>
    <b>Contact for place B</b><br>
    <img class="mail"> anotherr@email.com<br>
    <img class="phone"> +000 333 222 111
</p>
```

And there is a my `CSS`

```
html, body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.mail {
    background-image: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/net/stock_mail.png");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.phone {
    background-image: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/generic/stock_landline-phone.png");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle to better see it http://jsfiddle.net/vLkX8/1/

Now, where is the problem. As you can see there is a weird *border* on that image, I want to get rid of him and another problem is with a mail icon. Mail icon is bit higher than a text. How can I move it bottom?

Thank you.

Comment: you don't have valid markup.  you have an img element with no src attribute.  why don't you create a simple list item and define bg images for li.mail and li.phone elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (ab)using the img-tag for something it wasn't designed to do. Change the html to

```
<p>
    <b>Contact for place A</b><br>
    <div class="mail"></div> your@email.com<br>
    <div class="phone"></div> +000 111 222 333
</p>
<p>
    <b>Contact for place B</b><br>
    <div class="mail"></div> anotherr@email.com<br>
    <div class="phone"></div> +000 333 222 111
</p>
```

And the CSS to:

```
html, body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.mail {
    background-image: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/net/stock_mail.png");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
.phone {
    background-image: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/generic/stock_landline-phone.png");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sumurai8/7gzKB/

By using an inline div-tag it is properly borderless. I've added `display: inline-block`, so that the div will be properly displayed in an 'inline' context like this. `margin-bottom: -3px` will move the image 3 pixels down, by moving the bottom margin 3 pixels up.

Comment: Thanks, works great, just a detail. Delete margin-bottom: -3px; inside a .phone. :)

Comment: Without the negative margin, it isn't displayed correctly for me in IE9. Then again... it's IE. @chrisvillanueva's idea with li's might work better across browsers.

Comment: i mean that should be only in .mail class not in .phone class. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

img {vertical-align:bottom}

As for that border, it's quite simple: `<img>` MUST have a `src`. It is NOT valid to just specify a background image.

That said, you could create a 1x1 transparent pixel image and use that as the source, then use the background image in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i have a working sample that uses list items for markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/E67J2/

html:

```
<ul class="contact">
    <li class="li-header">Contact for place A</li>
    <li class="mail"> your@email.com </li>
    <li class="phone"> +000 111 222 333 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="contact">
    <li class="li-header">Contact for place B</li>
    <li class="mail"> anotherr@email.com</li>
    <li class="phone"> +000 333 222 111</li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul.contact{list-style:none;}
li.li-header{font-weight:bold;}
.mail {
    background: #fff url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/net/stock_mail.png") no-repeat 0% 50%;

}
.phone {
    background: #fff url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gnomeicontheme/16x16/stock/generic/stock_landline-phone.png") no-repeat 0% 50%;
}

.mail, .phone{
    padding-left:20px;

}
```

To me, you have a list of contacts.  Within each list, you have bulletpoint items about those contacts. It would be cleaner to make these list items with classes to distinguish among header, mail, and phone information.  If you take my approach, adding bg images for specific classes is easy and the markup is more semantic.

Also, it would be easy to address image positioning relative to text using my code.  You would need to edit background image positioning to line things up as needed.